# Regex: remove repeated last characters on a line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a CSV file generated by Excel, with lines that ends with a lot of comma:

```
1,toto,,,,,,,,
2,tata,10,2,,,,,,
3,titi,5,,,,,,,
```

How can I remove all the comma only at the end of each line so I can get:

```
1,toto
2,tata,10,2
3,titi,5
```

I am using the search and replace tool from Notepad++ that can use Regex.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
,+$
```

It matches one or more commas at the end of the line.

So put this as find pattern, and nothing as replace pattern (and don't forget to enable regex).

Answer (score 1):

Find

```
(.+?),+(\n|$)
```

Replace with :

```
\1\n
```